# Can't boot from USB on UEFI PEAQ PNB T2011-I0C1 360

Tags: system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I'm not sure this is the right community to ask.

I'm trying to install a fresh Arch Linux on a PEAQ Laptop that ran Windows 10 for 2-3 years. After multiple attempts, I can't fin a way to boot from my USB stick.

My UEFI setting are as follow:

- Secure Boot [Disabled]
- Secure Boot Mode [Standard]
- Quiet Boot [Disabled]
- Fast Boot [Disabled]

Boot Option # [UEFI: My USB, Partition 1] 
Boot Option #2 [Windows Boot Manager]

I tried multiple times with multiple settings and 2-3 distros (Arch, Archx32, Lubuntu) the computer always run the Windows Boot Manager. All my USB sticks are made using Rufus 3.8 with the last releases of the distros.
Has anyone ever encountered this situation?

Comment: What happens if you disable boot option #2? What error message do you get?

Comment: @dirkt I can't disable it, it's a list or priority. I can only select an other available boot option.

Comment: That's an interesting BIOS if you can't disable it ... can you take out the harddisk/SSD with Windows on it?

Comment: @dirkt it's the kind of small laptop that can be folded into a tablet. I'm not sure I can acces the Hard Drive to remove it. I'll look into it.

Comment: @dirkt So it appears I didn't looked enough. I can disable the boot options. When I try to do so, leaving only the USB stick, the system boots on Windows anyway.

Comment: What happens if you take out the USB stick in that situation? If it doesn't boot into Windows, then the boot loader on the USB stick is wrong, as it chain-boots into Windows. If it still boots into Windows, then you have an interesting BIOS that ignores the boot options and just always boots into the internal harddisk/SSD. In that case, you must try to take that out.

Comment: @dirkt I tried to remove the USB and the system still boots on Windows. After a bit of tinkering, I managed to acces the EFI shell. Can I boot from my USB from that ? I also tried to remove the Hard disk but couldn't find it in the mess that is the computer (glue everywhere) and it's a pretty small one (24Gb) that may be fixed to other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> made using Rufus 3.8

Is it officially known to work?  Rufus has been known to cripple hybrid ISOs for quite some time around me (like UltraISO or UNetBootin), so we ended up [recommending](http://en.altlinux.org/write) plain `dd` or `imagewriter`-- maybe try writing [ALT Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) this way and if it works, you at least know the path :-)

Another source of trouble might be 32-bit UEFI firmware with 64-bit capable CPU, you can run a 64-bit distro there but need 32-bit EFI bootloader (might also need `shim`) and a [`CONFIG_EFI_MIXED`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Efibootmgr#Linux_kernel_config_options_for_UEFI) kernel config option.

PS: the excellent [Rod's books](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) on the topic might give you some understanding of what goes on...

Comment: I remember seeing the system was a 32-bits Windows running on a 64-bits capable CPU. I look into that, thank you!

Comment: So the answer was in the 32-bit EFI bootloader. I used the one shipped with Fedora to replace the 64-bit one. Laptop works perfectly since.